# Debugging mix of QML and C++

Tags: c++, qt, qml, qtquick2

Is there any possibility to see the stack not only of QML or C++, but both of them? For example: I have a `QObject` child with a member function `foo()` marked as `Q_INVOKABLE`. In QML I have `MouseArea` and `onClicked` it calls `foo()`. If I set a breakpoint inside `foo()`, I would not be able to see from were from QML this call came.

Answer (score 0):

No, the QML and C++ debuggers are two separate applications. The QML debugger has no knowledge of C++ breakpoints, and vice versa.